# Proper signing of requests to aws resources through http

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is writing some data to an Elasticsearch domain I have also set up through AWS. Currently the access policy on my domain is just to allow my own IP address to work with the domain

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{
 "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
 "Action": "es:*",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:$ACCOUNT:domain/DOMAIN/*",
 "Condition": { "IpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": $MYIP } }
}]}
```

I found the [`aws4` library](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) for signing http requests. I'm using it as such:

```
axios(aws4.sign({
    host: process.env.ES_ENDPOINT,
    method: "post",
    url: `https://${process.env.ES_ENDPOINT}/foobot/foobot`,
    data,
}))
```

This was actually working before without the `aws4.sign` piece as I had the ES domain completely open, but now I've applied the IP address policy above.

Now, I continually get an error like this in response:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Is there something else I need to do to properly sign the request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually has to do with the two libraries, `axios` and `aws4`. `aws4` will sign based off of a normal NodeJS `http` request, and in a POST request with a body *the body is required* to properly sign the request.

This is fixed pretty simply by also passing in `body` and `path`

```
axios(aws4.sign({
    host: process.env.ES_ENDPOINT,
    method: "POST",
    url: `https://${process.env.ES_ENDPOINT}/foobot/foobot`,
    data,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    path: "/foobot/foobot",
}))
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can send the signed GET request? I'm making it like this, but getting the same error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

Here's my code:
axios(aws4.sign({
            host: env('ES_URI'),
            method: "GET",
            url: `${url}`,
            query: JSON.stringify(query),
            path: `/${ES_INDEX}`
        }));

Comment: `path` needs to include the query string

Comment: I'm facing very silly issue, when I am using this url: https://search-segment-sandbox-072751898297-cwtklgabkmeb662v4nicf7oepq.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/babyscripts I'm not getting error: 403, but when I use this url: https://search-segment-sandbox-072751898297-cwtklgabkmeb662v4nicf7oepq.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/babyscripts/patient/_search it's giving me 403 error. Could you help me in that?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `data` still in the request? Looks like invalid object notation

Comment: @MatthewWoo this is shorthand property syntax. It does the equivalent of `data: data`

Comment: How can we achieve the same using AWS credentials from env file?

Answer (score 5):

We found that there are AWS libraries that can handle things smoothly without having to share your credentials with the lambda via environment variables.

Here is a full example that allows a lambda to call an appysync endpoint. 
Adapting it to any other service should not be hard.

Hope it helps someone.

```
const { defaultProvider } = require('@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node');
const { SignatureV4 } = require('@aws-sdk/signature-v4');
const { Sha256 } = require('@aws-crypto/sha256-js');
const { HttpRequest } = require('@aws-sdk/protocol-http');
const axios = require('axios');

const signer = new SignatureV4({
  credentials: defaultProvider(),
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  service: 'appsync',
  sha256: Sha256,
});

/**
 * Send a signed graphQl request via http to appsync
 *
 * @param {string} appsyncUrl URL to reach GraphQL
 * @param {object} requestBody JSON stringified request object.
 * @returns {Promise} Request that has been sent
 */
async function send(appsyncUrl, requestBody) {
  const parsedUrl = new UrlParse(appsyncUrl);
  const endpoint = parsedUrl.hostname.toString();
  const path = parsedUrl.pathname.toString();
  const req = new HttpRequest({
    hostname: endpoint,
    path,
    method: 'POST',
    body: requestBody,
    headers: {
      host: endpoint,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  const signed = await signer.sign(req, { signingDate: new Date() });

  return axios
    .post(appsyncUrl, signed.body, { headers: signed.headers })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data && response.data.errors) {
        console.error({ error: response.data.errors }, 'Updating data failed');
      } else if (response.data) {
        return response.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error({ error, endpoint }, 'Failed to connect to graphQL server'));
}
```

usage:

```
const myGraphQlMutation = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation MyMutation($id: ID!, $status: String!) {
    myMutation(result: { id: $id, status: $status }) {
      id
      status
    }
  }
`;

const sendToAppSync = async (id, status) => {
  const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
    query: myGraphQlMutation,
    variables: {
      id: id,
      status: status,
    },
  });

  try {
    const response = await send(process.env.APPSYNC_ENDPOINT, requestBody);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`[ERROR] Error calling appsync: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`);
    throw error;
  }
```

Of course, you will need to have given the proper rights to your lambda IAM role. (this blog post [gives good](https://adrianhall.github.io/cloud/2018/10/26/backend-graphql-trigger-appsync/) pointers)

Comment: thanks. Are these two section together comprise the Lambda code? Where is the lambda handler exported?

Comment: @MorSagmon This is code can be used by a lambda. It creates a helper function (send) that will sign an http request sent to an AWS service (in this case appsync). You'll still need to wrap the example usage code in a handler.

Comment: So, only the second section (under "usage") needs to be wrapped by the handler then. Thanks!

Comment: @MorSagmon yes,that's it. The rest could be placed into a utility module

Comment: Because there's virtually no info on the internet, I just want to add that if you need to create a SigV4**a** signature (as opposed to SigV4) to call an S3 multi-region access point for example, replace the `SignatureV4` class with `CrtSignerV4` from `@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt`. It's more-or-less a drop-in replacement, but you have to specify `region: "*"` and `signingAlgorithm: 1` to indicate SigV4a.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i use this same example and it run successfully. But each time its return different signature. Even for same values.

```
axios(aws4.sign({
    host: process.env.ES_ENDPOINT,
    method: "POST",
    url: `https://${process.env.ES_ENDPOINT}/foobot/foobot`,
    data,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    path: "/foobot/foobot",
}))
```

Comment: Would that not be because it signs also with a timestamp. So based on time it would be different...

Answer (score 0):

The above answers have been helpful in bringing it all in to my solution here for posting a WS message from a lambda to the Websocket API in the API Gateway.

The reason for this was in order to avoid using the aws-sdk, which adds at least another ~2500ms on first run (warmup).

Here is my code for this, hope it helps others:

```
const data = {'success': true};
const request = {
    host: process.env.AWS_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT,
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://${process.env.AWS_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT}/wss/@connections/${connectionId}`, // this is for axios
    path: `/wss/@connections/${connectionId}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    data, // this is needed for axios
}

const signedRequest = aws4.sign(request,
    {
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN // needed when sending from a lambda
    });

    delete signedRequest.headers['Host']; // delete Host to not potentially mess with axios
    const response = await axios(signedRequest);
```